# Codeigniter:Helper functions are not loaded

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a form and without entering the data in fields when i submit it,it redirect on blank page instead of the page which open with form_open() after loading the form helper in my controller. In fact i am unable to use the functionality of the url helper.I have post this issue in another way but didn't get any solution. i have tried the below code from codeigniter documentation but it's not working for me.

Why this is happening . Please help me to solve it.

Controller:

```
class Login extends CI_Controller{
    function index()
    {
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('login_form');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('success');
    }
}
}
```

login_form view :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('login'); ?>

<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Password</h5>
<input type="text" name="password" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Password Confirm</h5>
<input type="text" name="passconf" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Email Address</h5>
<input type="text" name="email" value="" size="50" />

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

success view:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Your form was successfully submitted!</h3>

<p><?php echo anchor('form', 'Try it again!'); ?></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you are getting any error?

Comment: @Razib Al Mamun... it's not displaying any error. but after submitting it with blank field it redirects on a blank page.can you tell me why??

Comment: when it redirect blank page in this time which url in your browser

Comment: same question as Razib Al Mamun in other words: What is the url of the page after submitting? Is it the same as the initial one?

Comment: url of the page is => about:blank
....and nothing

Comment: try in your `index` method only `if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        echo "Need all input field";
    }` and remove `else`, now submit and let me know

Comment: @Razib Al Mamun... now it echo this value after submitting the blank form.But why validation is not working?

Comment: are you getting `Need all input field` after submitting?

Comment: oh, i thinks your problem is not `url_helpers`

Comment: I thinks form_helper is working for me. can you tell me why?

Comment: i have submitted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>$this->load->helper('form', 'url'); 
instead of  `$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));`
should work ok.</strike>

**Edit:** Not sure what the problem is, but did you try loading the helpers inside `/application/config/autoload.php` ?

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('form', 'url');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct did you configure your .htaccess file. Because i tried your code it all working fine.When i submit the blank form its give validation error.

**code for .htaccess file**

```
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: sir actually that's a problem when i submit the blank form it's redirect on a blank page without displaying validation error.I have also edit .htaccess file.

Comment: I am not sure why its showing blank page because i tried your code in my local server its not showing blank page.When i submit the blank form its shows validation error.

Comment: Thanks.. for answering

Answer (score 0):

do you add `parent::__construct()` in your `__construct()` ?

```
    class Login extends CI_Controller{
        public function __construct()
        {   
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        }  
        ....
```

Comment: i have tried it but it still redirects on a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

In your `login` controller :

```
<?php
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    public function index() {
        $data = array();
        $data['title'] = 'Login Form';
        $this->load->view('login_form', $data);
    }

    public function save() {     
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE)
        {
            redirect('login/success');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->index();
        }
    }

    public function success() {
        $data = array();
        $data['title'] = 'Successfully Submitted';
        $this->load->view('success_view', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

Change form action in your login view page

```
<?php echo form_open('login/save'); ?>
```

or

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>login/save">
```

Note :  You can run your login form in your browser like `http://localhost/project_folder/login/`

Comment: Sir, I have replace my code with your code but still it redirects on a blank page having url  about:blank....what's wrong with it please aware me to this.

Comment: ha...ha...ha..ha..ha..ha... nothing to say.

Comment: are you joking with me?

Comment: Nooooo... i am not joking i am facing this problem at this time and i have tried it with different version of codeigniter and with all way which is usefull for loading helpers but facing same problem that's why i have post my problem here

Comment: Sir skype is not allow here ;(

Comment: codeigniter 2.2.6 but i also tried with current version 3.1.2

Comment: Ok.. i am waiting for your sol'n.

Comment: did you get that?

Comment: give me you Teamviewer id pass

Answer (score 0):

Could try creating a construct class

> Make sure file name is Login.php **first letter only** is all ways upper
>   case codeigniter ucfirst sometimes can cause issues if not done like [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming)

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    function index() {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('login_form');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('success');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: same issue as i discussed before.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this

```
parent::__construct();
```

to your constructor, so

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}
```